# Outlook Add-in for Outlook 2013 app debugger

Tags: outlook-addin

I am using Outlook 2013 application to test the Outlook add-in I am creating. At the moment, when I click a button on my add-in, it is just saying App Error and I don't know what is causing it.

Is there a way for me to debug my code to see where the error is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I depends on your windows version, have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10).

For Windows 10:

> Launch the F12 development tools that corresponds to your version of Office:
>
> For the 32-bit version of Office, use C:\Windows\System32\F12\IEChooser.exe
>
> For the 64-bit version of Office, use C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12\IEChooser.exe